# How to process only the last file in a directory using Apache Camel's file component

Tags: apache-camel

I have a directory with files likes this:

```
inbox/
  data.20130813T1921.json
  data.20130818T0123.json
  data.20130901T1342.json
```

I'm using Apache Camel 2.11 and on process start, I only want to process one file: the latest.  The other files can actually be ignored. Alternatively, the older files can be deleted once a new file has been processed.

I'm configuring my component using the following, but it obviously doesn't do what I need:

```
file:inbox/?noop=true
```

`noop` does keep the last file, but also all other files. On startup, Camel processes all existing files, which is more than I need.

What is the best way to only process the latest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the sorting and then sort by name, and possible need to reverse it so the latest is first / last. You can try it out to see which one you need. And then set maxMessagesPerPoll=1 to only pickup one file. And you need to set eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false to allow to sort before limiting the number of files.

You can find details at: http://camel.apache.org/file2. See the section *Sorting using sortBy* for the sorting.

Comment: On each poll, an older file is processed. Only one per cycle, but I'll be reading older files. Looking into the other answer now.

Comment: In the consumer, once I keep track of which file is the latest one. Once I've processed it, any other files which are "older" that the first file are simply deleted using `new File(message.getHeader(Exchange.FILE_PATH).toString).delete()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to still using the sorting to ensure the latest file is last. Then you can use the aggregator EIP to aggregate all the files, and use `org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.UseLatestAggregationStrategy` as the aggregation strategy to only keep the last (which would be the latest file). Then you can instruct the file endpoint to delete=true to delete the files when done. You would then also need to configure the aggregator to `completionFromBatchConsumer=true`.

The aggregator eip is documented here: http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2